# Magento+ Add to cart is not working

Tags: mysql, magento

When I click on 'add to cart' button then it is not working.

This message 'Cannot add the item to shopping cart.' is displayed.

When I check log then this Exception is coming:

```
Exception message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'website_ids' in 'where clause', query was:
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `salesrule` AS `main_table` WHERE (is_active=1) AND (find_in_set(1, website_ids)) AND
(find_in_set(0, customer_group_ids)) AND
(main_table.coupon_type = 1) AND
(from_date is null or from_date<='2015-08-20')
AND (to_date is null or to_date>='2015-08-20') ORDER BY `sort_order` ASC
```

Please suggest me.

Thanks

Trilok Gupta

Comment: Are you looking for a programmatic solution to this problem? Or are you trying to fix a Magento error?

Answer (score 1):

You are either running a VERY old Magento version or code that is not compatible with Magento 1.7+.

- The `website_ids` column has been added in Magento 1.1.1<sup>*</sup>. Some code that is not backwards compatible would throw the error on versions below that.
- The column has been remvoed again in Magento 1.7.0.0<sup>**</sup>. Code that is written for Magento 1.6 or older and not made compatible with 1.7 yet, will throw this error too.

---

<sup>*) 
https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d19f0e13d3d2fcbcc2d8fa6073568d5f95442470/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/sql/salesrule_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.4-0.7.5.php</sup>

<sup>**) https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/e56274a1b0954bc3744392ae8496271087f9445c/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/sql/salesrule_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.2-1.6.0.3.php</sup>

Comment: i am using 1.9.2.0 version.

Comment: I checked again. The column has been removed in 1.7, see updated answer

Comment: Yeah, but what is the solution of above question. how i can fix it?

Comment: Look at the exception stack trace to find out which extension is causing it, then update (or remove) this extension